# Is it possible to set a download limit in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

Is it possible to set a download limit in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Also, is there is a way to download applications installation files for offline use?

Comment: Limiting what? Space, number of downloads, number of files, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the bandwith limit on apt-get which is still what Ubuntu software Center and Synaptic use to get packages (I believe) is fairly simple.  If you go into the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d directory you can add Acquire::http::Dl-Limit "70"; ("70" being the kb/s) in whichever parts of apt you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can download packages without installing them by using apt-get's -d option, used like this: `sudo apt-get install -d packagename` downloads the files for packagename. You can then run `sudo apt-get install packagename` offline to install the package. As far as putting restrictions, I don't know what you mean. You can make an account non-administrator so it prompts for a password of another user to install software.

Comment: i upvoted this because it, like the accepted answer, answered one of the questions.